# Why are the predicate version of lower_bound and upper_bound passing the iterator value inconsistently?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

In `upper_bound`'s binary predicate, the iterator value is passed as the second argument while in `lower_bound` the iterator value is passed as the first argument.

What is the reasoning here? And does it matter if I remember this detail or not when writing my own binary predicates?

---

**NOTE** my reference is www.cplusplus.com (which I am told may not be the best reference) and I confirmed it by looking at the implementation in the `stl` library shipped with `VC++`.

Comment: The algorithms use less than to compare elements ( ! (a < b) and !(b < a) ) means equivalent)

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about.  Did you check out the reference documentation of [`std::upper_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) and [`std::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) on `cppreference.com`?  It should be your go-to resource for looking up standard library docs.

Comment: It's probably so that you can use the same predicate for `std::sort` and `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound` and so on, which all use the predicate as a "less than" relation.

Comment: @5gon12eder `Comparison comp` is called as `comp(element, value)` in `lower_bound` and `comp(value, element)` in `upper_bound`.

Comment: @GuyGreer Okay, I see what you (and presumably the OP) mean now.  Note however that it is `comp(*it, value)` versus `!comp(value, *it)` so it is really an implementation detail and there is nothing one would have to remember about this, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @5gon12eder It can make a difference when `value` and `*it` have different types.  If they are not convertible then you have to pass a function pointer with the correct ordering, which may mean having two functions instead of one.  There are ways around this, and usually it's not a big deal, but it can still surprise you.

Comment: @5gon12eder Sure, in some cases you pass a functor (predicate) providing three `bool operators () (a, b)`: element < element, element < key and key < element

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is intentional. The reasoning is so you can use the same comparator for both algorithms. Consider the descriptions. [`lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound):

> Returns an iterator pointing to the first element in the range [first, last) that is *not less* than (i.e. greater or equal to) value.

and [`upper_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound):

> Returns an iterator pointing to the first element in the range [first, last) that is *greater* than value.

Consider that the standard comparator is `<`. In order to implement both algorithms with only `<` would require `!(elem < value)` for one and `value < elem` for the other. The inversion of the order of arguments just follows directly from that.

This shouldn't affect how you implement your Comparator though.